# Do I have to use standard shared UserDefaults object?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

As a convention, when dealing with [`UserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults), we use the [`standard`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1416603-standard) object of it. However, using the standard `UserDefaults` should set/get values that are accessible from a new instance and vise versa. To clarify:

```
let object = UserDefaults()
object.set(101, forKey: "number1") // setting via a new object
UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "number1") // getting via standard
// 101

UserDefaults.standard.set(102, forKey: "number2") // setting via standard
object.value(forKey: "number2") // getting via the new object
// 102
```

I would assume that `standard` is not exists as "syntactic sugar", it doesn't seem to be sensible to create a singleton class just for this purpose.

So:

- Is there benefit(s) of using `standard` instead of `UserDefaults()`? If there is, what is it? Could it be related to the suites?
- If there is something behind it, why are we even able to declare `UserDefaults()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Calling `UserDefaults()` is the same as calling `UserDefaults(suiteName: nil)`.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414356-init)

[Calling `UserDefaults(suiteName: nil)` returns an object that behaves like `UserDefaults.standard`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1409957-init):

> If you pass `nil` to this parameter, the system uses the default search list that the `standard` class method uses.

So there is no advantage in using `UserDefaults()` instead of `UserDefaults.standard`.

The advantage of using `UserDefaults.standard` instead of `UserDefaults()` is that only a single `UserDefaults.standard` object exists, so it may be faster and may use less memory to use `UserDefaults.standard` than to create a new object by calling  `UserDefaults()`.